# OpenCV Opencl Compilation error: 'X' is not declared in this scope

Tags: opencv, opencl

Hi I created a program using OpenCV in windows with visual studio. My program has two cpp files. Both of them include many library files. The main function is in detect.cpp file and the other file is lbp.cpp.

In windows the program runs just fine and can get every library files and header files. But when I tried to compile the program in Linux OpenCV it did not compile and gave me error. The lbp.cpp file cannot find opencl's function and data type. It gives me this error:

‘cl_command_queue’ was not declared in this scope 
‘cl_mem’ was not declared in this scope 
‘cl_int’ was not declared in this scope

There are many of them. Anyone has an idea how to solve them? I checked other sample filesin opencv OpenCl samples and used the same headers as they used. But my program just does not compile. Please help.

Comment: have you included "CL/cl.h" in lbp.cpp? every cpp file or headers in cpp file have to include cl.h. Also include opencl sdk include in your makefile unless its in /usr/include or /usr/local/include. -I/path/to/sdk/include

Comment: Hi krishnaraj, I included the cl.h header and now some of the errors are not showing. I checked the sample codes, they did not have included cl.h and they are working fine. Why I had to include explicitely? Another error I am getting is that ‘openCLCreateBuffer’ is not a member of ‘cv::ocl’. Could you help me why I am getting this and how to resolve this? I used this line in code:   cl_mem dclassified = ocl::openCLCreateBuffer(clCxt, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int));

Comment: oh. Looks openCLCreateBuffer() prototype is missing in https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ocl/include/opencv2/ocl.hpp . Its definition is here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ocl/src/initialization.cpp#L432 . Add its prototype to your ocl.hpp

Comment: I added this and it worked but I had to manually add such headers to many other files. That should not be the case. In some sample files they use this function and those function can automatically link to the necessary file without adding their location in the header. How the samples can automatically link and my code does not?Any idea?